# ServiceStack Razor not finding right view

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I have a [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) site that uses [ServiceStack.Razor](http://razor.servicestack.net) without issue.  I upgraded from 4.0.50 to 5.1.0 - with no other substantive changes - and now the Razor view engine is not rendering for service methods with a `DefaultView`.  If I instead return an `HttpResult` and set the view that way, it **does** work.  Did the behavior change from 4.x to 5.1, or am I missing something?

Original (works):

```
    [DefaultView("UploadRetailerReports")]
    public object Get(AdminHome request)
    {
        return new HttpResult()
        {
        };
    }
```

After (required workaround):

```
    public object Get(AdminHome request)
    {
        return new HttpResult()
        {
            View = "UploadRetailerReports"
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested a `[DefaultView]` attribute as a class and action attribute in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/75ed84079c3ba277bd86ba3c7610752eadfe6eec) and they're both working as expected and rendering the selected View.

Comment: Ung - no code formatting in comments, but when I return a `new object()` for the model, it seems to work. Leaving it null silently fails the ViewPage selection somehow.  Still stinks I need to touch all of my services, but such is life.  Now on to the broken LoadSelect (order by in subclause) :(

Comment: @jklemmack yeah `null` response returns a 204 empty response. But you can just return the `request` since your View ignores the model.